# How can I find the effect of error in value of variable in an equation?

Tags: calculus, probability

A few months back I published a paper and recently in our internal meeting, I was giving a presentation on that paper. One of the listeners raised a very interesting question which I believe can lead me to a small conference paper if I somehow find the solution of that question (sorry for such a long preface).

Here is the problem with $M, N$ as constants. I found the optimal value of $\phi$ by differentiation method. Now $D$ is the input to the system which I have assumed to be constant, but in practical scenarios, it can vary vastly. My question is How can I find the effect of $D$. What approach should I take?

(In other words, if I take $D$ as a constant value coming out of the system, how can I calculate the percentage of error allowed so as not to affect the $\phi^*$)

If needed, the following are the equations.

$$p= \phi(1-\frac{\phi}{M})(1-\frac{\phi}{MN})^D$$
and toptimal value of $\phi$ is:
$$\phi^* = \frac{M}{2D}(2N+(D-1)-\sqrt{4N^2-4N+D^2-2D+1})$$

---

PS: Not sure what tag I should use

Comment: How do you find the effect of a small change of a parameter? You differentiate

Comment: I don't understand. D is input or output? M and N are constants, but what is p and Phi?Is p a function of Phi?

Comment: p is the output probability, $\phi\in \{.25,.5,.75,1.0\}$ is the probability of some event. $D$ is the input. actual output is $p \in [0,1]$. Optimal $\phi^*$ is rounded off to the nearest of the defined 4 values.

Answer (score 1):

Let f(D) be the optimal value with the the imput of D.
If the error of D is dD, then the error of f,
df(D) = f'(D) dD approximately.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention a very important point i.e. $f(D)$ is monotonically decreasing w.r.t. $D$

Comment: hmm....I calculated $f'(d)$ and the value comes in negative, should I take the absolute value for the error or is it wrong?